# How to find the pole order of $z_0=0$ for $\frac{z^3}{1+z-\exp(z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

> Find the poler order of $z_0=0$ for:  $$\frac{z^3}{1+z-\exp(z)}$$

I can't see an easy way with that, is imposible find the Laurent series of that without search $a_n, b_n.$

Comment: Suppose $z_0$ is a root of $f$. What ways can you find the multiplicity of this root?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I corrected some details of the question.

Comment: The behavior at zero is much easier than poles elsewhere. Hint: you can expand the denominator easily.

Comment: Looks to me as if the thing doesn’t even have a pole at zero. Why don’t you try L’Hospital on it?

Comment: to simplify what Chris wrote below: $\exp(z) = 1+z + \mathcal O(z^2)$. Conclude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$e^z=1+z+z^2/2+z^3/6+\dots$.  You can factor $z^2$ out of the denominator, and the other factor is $-(1/2+z/6+z^2/24\dots)$.  The $z^2$ cancels, and we have $f(0)=0$.